# Как можно сделать AutoSize для RichTextBox'а?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!
Как можно сделать AutoSize для RichTextBox'а? Может есть какие нибудь библиотеки?

Comment: @cas-live опишите вопрос конкретнее. Что значит "Изменение размера по содержимому (Например Panel)"? Вы что, хотите засунуть в RichTextBox панель?

Comment: @DreamChild Нет я не хочу засунуть панель в RichTextBox! Например в RichTextBox внесли текст и этот текст не помещается в размеры RichTextBox'а, и он должен увеличиться!

Comment: 1) так при чем тут все-таки та панель, о которой вы говорили? 

2) что должно в таком случае происходить с RichTextBox если внесенный в него текст ну очень большой (скажем, больше одного экрана), такой, что сколько ни разворачивай RichTextBox, этот текст в нем не уместится?

Comment: 1) Панель для примера т.к. в ней есть свойство AutoSize
2) Не чего не должно произойти

Comment: что значит "ничего"? Вообще ничего? То есть даже текст не должен вставиться? Изъясняйтесь пожалуйста конкретнее, неужели из вас каждое слово надо вытаскивать клещами?

Comment: Должен появиться Scroll

Comment: >Должен появиться Scroll

замечательно. Тогда чем вас не устраивает задать изначальный максимально возможный размер для RichTextBox, который по мере заполнения будет прокручиваться? Приведенный вами пример с панелью совершенно не в тему, поскольку панель - это контрол немного другого порядка - он действительно может (и должен) растягиваться в соответствии с содержимым, а RichTextBox вместо растягивания имеет скроллы чтобы вмещать в себя любое содержимое.
Я что-то не припомню таких текстбоксов, которые бы меняли размеры по содержимому. Так что по всей вероятности выше желание несколько странно

Comment: Я уже сам все придумал! Спасибо за ответы!